# How to interface buzzer with LED in this circuit

Tags: voltage, led, circuit-design, buzzer

Below is the circuit where I want to integrate the buzzer with the red LED.

[image]

The task is to add the buzzer, where the red LED is, in such a way that when the red LED (which is driven by the LED driver) turns ON, the buzzer should turn ON. When the red LED turns OFF the buzzer should turn OFF.

In the circuit you have 5V supply voltage. The red LED has voltage drop of 1.95V; the output pin (IO0) of the LED driver has a low level output voltage of 0.7V; the resistor is calculated to have a voltage drop of 2.35V. Additionally, the buzzer has an operating voltage of 1.5V. Adding the buzzer in series with the LED won't work, as there wouldn't be enough voltage for the buzzer to turn ON.

Could anyone suggest a method for adding the buzzer to the circuit?

Please refer to the below datasheets of the main components.

**Links to components:**

Buzzer Datasheet
https://docs.rs-online.com/296f/0900766b8135f7a7.pdf

LED Datasheet
https://www.kingbright.com/attachments/file/psearch/000/00/00/KPTR-3216SURCK(Ver.23A).pdf

Resistor datasheet
https://www.yageo.com/upload/media/product/productsearch/datasheet/rchip/PYu-RC_Group_51_RoHS_L_12.pdf

LED Driver datasheet
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9536.pdf

Comment: Just connect the buzzer between +5V and the output of U3.

Comment: upvote for well written question

Comment: `buzzer has an operating voltage of 1.5V` ... read the buzzer datasheet again

Comment: The buzzer has a very low sound level when fed 1.5V, is louder with 5V and is fairly loud at its maximum operating voltage. I did not lookup the output voltage and current of the driver IC.

Comment: When the LED is off, is the pin IO0 of U3 at high impedance (disconnected), or is it at 5v?  Also...  Which model buzzer? SMA-13 (1.8mA), SMA-13LT (11.6mA), or SMA-13LC (0.7mA)? And if you could specify the voltage and power you would like it to operate, I could provide a circuit.